How to set up a homepage without index.html
In a lot of websites, there is a homepage e.g. Stack Overflow. These websites, however, do not have an index.html file: Stack Overflow. How do I do that with my websites?
Related: How do I make webpages without a file name? The way I'm doing it now is to create a directory with only index.html in it, so I assume a similar solution can be used here.

You are asking two different questions. Please focus on asking only one question (and check if the question doesn't already exists). In both cases, add the name of the webserver application you are using to your question.

Web server configuration questions may fit better on [webmasters.se]

bruhhh the thing is by default most web browsers search for the index.html file to load.if you are planning to host the page in github pages..i dont think it would be possible but you could purchase a domain to mask the path.
butt happy news for ya if ure using apache or nginx server.. there you could change the default file to load ..here you can add another html file instead of index.html
forr eg: in the server config file
DefaultType html/file
DirectoryIndex whatever.html

here whatever.html would the first file to load..index.html naming is not needed here though

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
